# Installing Managed DirectX 9 on Win8

Tags: windows, .net, windows-8

As part of a project I'm involved in, we're installing DirectX9 (including managed DirectX) components as part of our installation software.
Before installing the DirectX we're installing .NET4.

When we moved to Win8 we started to see some issues with the DX installation and we're finally found the root cause which is that managed DirectX9 components are not installed when there is no .NET framework between v1 to v3.5 installed.

We can install the .NET as part of our installation (in addition to .NET4) but there are 2 problems:
1. On Win8 you cannot run the .NET installation executable, only via 'Add Features' API.
2. Installing via the 'Add Features' requires an internet connection for downloading the .NET which is not feasible in our system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly have absolutely no Internet connectivity, [you can install .NET 3.5 using DISM and a copy of the Windows installation media](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx#sectionToggle2).

For example:

```
dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:d:\sources\sxs
```

Comment: Thanks but the existence of windows installation media during our system's installation is not possible.

Comment: You're going to have to change _something_ about what is or is not possible. What you are asking for is _impossible_.

Comment: I was afraid that will be the answer, thank you very much